# How should an invariant List be implemented in Scala?

Tags: scala

I want to implement a linked list in Scala where the type parameter is invariant, unlike the standard library `List`.

Here is an attempt:

```
sealed trait InvariantList[T]
case object Nil extends InvariantList[_]
case class Cons[T](head : T, tail : InvariantList[T]) extends InvariantList[T]

object InvariantList {
  def map[A, B](xs : InvariantList[A])(f : A => B) : InvariantList[B] = {
    xs match {
      case Nil => Nil[B]
      case Cons(head, tail) => Cons(f(head), map(tail)(f))
    }
  }
}

object Example {
  val xs = Cons(7, Cons(5, Nil[Int]))
  InvariantList.map(xs)(_ + 1)
}
```

This is pretty close to what I want, but it is annoying to have to specify the type parameter of `Nil` in the implementation of `map` and in the example use.

I also tried using `case class Nil[T]() extends InvariantList[T]`, but this is also ugly because I have to put the parens all over the place.

What is the recommended way of defining `Nil` in an invariant linked list implementation? I think the question applies more generally to any invariant data structure that has cases with empty constructors. I would like it to be as convenient to use as the standard library `List` (convenient in that I don't have to specify the type parameter or add parens).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard library doesn't have a `Nil` element for its invariant collections. For example, `Set` and `ListBuffer` are invariant, but they do not have `Nil` sub-type. They require you to say `Set.empty[A]` or `ListBuffer.empty[A]`.

```
scala> val l : ListBuffer[Int] = Nil
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type
 required: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]
       val l : ListBuffer[Int] = Nil
                                 ^

scala> val set: Set[Int] = Nil
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type
 required: Set[Int]
       val set: Set[Int] = Nil
                           ^
```

Having a single `case object Nil extends InvariantList[_]` won't work because of invariance. Every list type would require it's own empty representation. Because an empty `List[Dog]` would not be the same as an empty `List[Animal]`, if `Dog <: Animal`, etc.

What you're essentially asking for is a singleton symbol `Nil` to be treated like many different types.  I think you're on the right track with a case class, because that will allow you one `Nil[A]` per list type. Unfortunately that will never allow you to pattern-match on `Nil`, only `Nil()`, because you need an extractor with parameters and not one for a singleton (which your `Nil` is not). If you want the convenience of not writing the type parameter and parentheses, you can write a method like this in the same package:

```
def nil[A] = Nil[A]()
```

It's not ideal, but it will partially solve your problem. Putting it all together:

```
sealed trait InvariantList[A]

case class Nil[A]() extends InvariantList[A]

case class Cons[A](head : A, tail : InvariantList[A]) extends InvariantList[A]

object InvariantList {

  def map[A, B](xs : InvariantList[A])(f : A => B) : InvariantList[B] = {
    xs match {
      case Nil() => nil
      case Cons(head, tail) => Cons(f(head), map(tail)(f))
    }
  }

}

scala> val xs = Cons(7, Cons(5, nil))
xs: Cons[Int] = Cons(7,Cons(5,Nil()))

scala> InvariantList.map(xs)(_ + 1)
res0: InvariantList[Int] = Cons(8,Cons(6,Nil()))
```

Comment: There's also the possible of an implicit conversion, but it would be ugly.