# Enforce Scala Seq to use a single type only (no LUB)

Tags: scala, collections, compile-time, typechecking

I would like to create and use a `Seq[T]` collection in Scala
and ensure that it only use one type. So if I use:

```
val l = List(1, 2, 2.0)
```

a compile time error should occur - `List` elements should all be 
`Double` or all `Int`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34118720/2541573

Comment: Perhaps you may find this interesting: http://eed3si9n.com/stricter-scala-with-ynolub

Comment: From the responses, it seems that avoiding the LUB requires that I either specify the type when declaring the collections or changing the compiler behaviour.  I was hopping some magic type-level programming would solve this. Thanks to @Jubobs and stefanobaghino for the help.

Comment: There is a standard way to do it for any _fixed_ number of arguments, but I don't think there is one for varargs.

Comment: Yes. I have done this with two parameters and the =:= type-level operator. For collections I have yet to find a way. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Perhaps this is linter territory rather than language territory.

Comment: @SethTisue Don't think so. I think this type class programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `-Xlint:infer-any` compiler [flag](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/compiler-options/index.html)

> Warn when a type argument is inferred to be `Any`

which in combination with fatal warnings at least prevents worst case LUB scenario where `Any` is inferred

```
scala -Xlint:infer-any -Werror -e 'List(42, 3.14, "picard")'
warning: a type was inferred to be `Any`; this may indicate a programming error.
List(42, 3.14, "picard")
^
error: No warnings can be incurred under -Werror.
```

however note this will not help if LUB is narrower than `Any`, for example

```
scala -Xlint:infer-any -Werror -e 'Vector(List(1), Set(2))'
```

raises no warning. Another flag that might help is `-Wnumeric-widen`

> Warn when numerics are widened.

for example

```
scala -Wnumeric-widen -Xlint:infer-any -Werror -e 'def f(i: Int, d: Double): List[Double] = List(i, d)'
warning: implicit numeric widening
def f(i: Int, d: Double): List[Double] = List(i, d)
                                              ^
error: No warnings can be incurred under -Werror.
```